# Google Sheets Scatter plot with multiple data sets and independent axis

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I want to create a scatter plot in Google Sheets to display several sets of `x` and `y` coordinates, such that every five sets are a different color and a different element on the legend.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Without even a sketch I am not sure what is required but a layout as shown may help:

[image: WA106168 example]

Comment: This maps the X values into a single set of integers, with some Y values missing or eempty for some Xs. I.e. a sparse set.  How about if *every* Y value from every set of values has a different X?  Sure, you can always do the sparse thing - but then if you have N sets of (x,y) coordinates, you will need total # of rows = the total count of all points in all sets of (x,y) values Which is clumsy. // I.e. how can one plot two or more independent scatter plots, where the X coordinates have different values for each - without having to sparsify?